# Is css-loader neccessary if you use postcss-loader with appropriate plugins?

Tags: webpack, postcss, css-loader, postcss-import, postcss-loader

I'm using `postcss-import` to take care of my imports, and `cssnano` to minify. In my Webpack config I've been using the following setup for `css-loader`...

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    url: false,
    import: false,
    minimize: false,
    importLoaders: 1,
    souceMap: true,
  }
}
```

...but when I remove that everything still seems to load fine, so now I just have `post-css` before `style-loader`. Can I safely omit `css-loader` from my css build, or is there some other functionality it provides that is necessary? I've yet to see a `webpack.config.js` file that doesn't use `css-loader`, so I want to be cautious here! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`css-loader` basically enables webpack to build your dependencies tree by following the dependencies declared as `@import` and `url()` in you CSS files.

From [css-loader docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#usage):

> The css-loader interprets @import and url() like import/require() and will resolve them.

Since `postcss-import` handles CSS `@imports`, you will still need `css-loader` to bundle any other static asset imported by your stylesheets like images, fonts, etc...

Comment: "you will still need css-loader to bundle any other static asset imported by your stylesheets like images, fonts, etc" - doesn't "file-loader" handle that?